# APPLICATION FAILED TO START Error starting ApplicationContext

Tags: spring, spring-security

when I run this error comes pleas help me to solve this

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-02-11 10:53:55.839 ERROR 8804 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field userDao in com.example.spring.security.api.service.UserServiceImpl required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.

Comment: could you post your configuration class here , also which version of spring you're using , seems your missing to create the entityManagerFactory bean ( in case of non spring boot app !)

Answer (score 0):

What annotations are you using? Could be that you are using some annotation that tells Spring boot to not use some autoconfiguration.

You probably want `HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration` to run.